# No response from httprequest through urllib2/ requests in gunicorn

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2, gunicorn

I have a python app, using flask to create the front end.

I'm making a number of requests to a server and most are successful. After around 5/6 requests I stop receiving any reply at all. Not even a 404/ 500 response code. And it seems to crash the method the request was called from as the program just moves to the next method, with no error message.

This only seems to happen when running the python app using gunicorn. Running from 'python app.py' it works perfectly.

I've changed my code to work with both urllib2 and the requests library.

I've tried using an older version of python as suggested here: [http request inside gunicorn causes gunicorn response to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918378/http-request-inside-gunicorn-causes-gunicorn-response-to-fail) but to no success.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was simply a timeout issue with apache.

Answer (score 0):

404/500 are server-side responses so it's not your client code. If you have access to server logs I'd recommend that you take a look why it happens as usually it gives a problem detailing why it happened - my guess is that you're rate-limited by a firewall, service is not very well written to handle/use multi-threading, or you're locking up the back-end with too many client connections so the client fails on the "server threadcount+1" connection.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with limited rates or too many connections as when I run it using the flask server it works fine. However, when I use gunicorn it fails. However I need to use gunicorn to daemonize the application.

Comment: What's in the logs for gunicorn when you do get this error?